# Make an absolute parent Div Width equal to the total absolute child Div's Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to do is not fit the childs inside the parent, not want the children to be responsive I just want the parent fit the overall fixed `width` of his childs to then center it properly

What I'm trying to do is:

> A widget that can be centered regardless of the contents inside, so if
>   there are 5 childs appears centered, if there's 10 stills centered

I'm trying to make a "responsive" `div` with a dynamically created `div` childs, with those being `absolute` because they need to overlap themselves a bit

The thing is, the parent doesn't seem to detect their childs at all when putting them on `absolute`

I know this is somewhat possible because when using `overflow` the parent knows somehow the overall `width`

Is there any way to make the outer parent `div`'s `width` equal to the total's `width` of their childs?

Have been searching all damn morning reviewing lots of questions and none seemed to answer that, I'm aware that most surely this is not the better approach for this and will be kindly grateful knowing other methods

**What I've GOT:**

```css
.grandparent{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 50%; bottom: 0; border: solid; }

.parent { position: absolute; width: 90%; height: 85%; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border: red solid; }

.child { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 150px; border: blue solid; }
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(0em, 16px) rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(3.6em, 21px) rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(7.2em, 25px) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put the **Parent (red square) Centered Horizontally**, no matter whats inside because childs count may vary

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you shared the code you are working with.

Comment: okay i will try of course

Comment: This is simplified of the overall work

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but may I suggest that you start by removing `absolute` positioning from your child elements.  You did that just to get them to overlap, which can be achieved other ways.

Comment: I'm trying to do a widget that can be centered regardless of the contents inside, so if there are 5 childs appears centered, if there's 10 stills centered

But anyway you're right, doing that overlap by other means it will definitively work

Any good direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution without removing the `absolute` positioning from my child elements !

Used `overflow` to then be able to get the **total width of the children** with `scrollWidth`

`var A = document.getElementById('parent').scrollWidth`

And knowing the true width of the `parent's div` I can then center it properly without further problems

`$('#parent').width(A);` or `document.getElementById('parent').style.width = A + "px";`

**Workin' Snippet**

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.style.width = parent.scrollWidth + "px";

var parent2 = document.getElementById('parent2');

parent2.style.width = parent2.scrollWidth + "px";
```

```css
.body { height: 500px;}    

.grandparent{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 200px; top: 0; border: solid; }

.parent { position: absolute; height: 100%; overflow: visible; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border: red solid; }

.child { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 150px; border: blue solid; }

.grandparent2{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 200px; top: 200px; border: solid; }

.parent2 { position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: visible; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border: red solid; }

.h41, .h42 { position: absolute; left:20px; }
.h41 { top: 20px; }
.h42 { top: 220px;}
```

```html
<h4 class="h41">Centered with 5 Childs</h4>
<div class="grandparent">
    <div id="parent" class="parent">
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(0em, 16px) rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(3.6em, 21px) rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(7.2em, 25px) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(11em, 21px) rotateZ(10deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(15.2em, 25px) rotateZ(20deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<h4 class="h42">Centered with 2 Childs</h4>
<div class="grandparent2">
    <div id="parent2" class="parent2">
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(0em, 16px) rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
        <div class="child" style="transform: translate(5em, 21px) rotateZ(10deg) rotateY(0deg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```